# Incredibly basic lxml questions: getting HTML/string content of lxml.etree._Element?

Tags: python, lxml

This is such a basic question that I actually can't find it in the docs :-/

In the following:

```
img = house_tree.xpath('//img[@id="mainphoto"]')[0]
```

How do I get the HTML of the `<img/>` tag?

I've tried adding `html_content()` but get `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'html_content'`.

Also, it was a tag with some content inside (e.g. `<p>text</p>`) how would I get the content (e.g. `text`)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I suppose it will be as simple as:

```
from lxml.etree import tostring
inner_html = tostring(img)
```

As for getting content from inside `<p>`, say, some selected element `el`:

```
content = el.text_content()
```

Comment: I am getting: `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'`